# show 1 primary key from master in left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello Everyone I want Join 2 table with 1 coloumn in master I use for primary key. but I just want Show 1 Value from joined table where Primary key exist
I use this but not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_noc.nik, employee_noc.name, employee_noc.position, employee_noc.contract_start, evaluasi_employe.tanggal FROM `employee_noc` 
LEFT JOIN evaluasi_employe ON evaluasi_employe.nik=employee_noc.nik AND employee_noc.status LIKE '%AKTIF%'
```

[image]

This master table (Employee)
[image]

This Table What I want Join:
[image]

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what is _master_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed from your query the evaluasi_employe that have a tanggal that is not the latest

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_noc.nik, employee_noc.name, employee_noc.position, employee_noc.contract_start, evaluasi_employe.tanggal 
FROM `employee_noc` 
LEFT JOIN evaluasi_employe ON evaluasi_employe.nik=employee_noc.nik AND employee_noc.status LIKE '%AKTIF%'
and not exists
(
 Select 1 from evaluasi_employe b where b.nik = evaluasi_employe.nik 
 and evaluasi_employe.tanggal < b.tanggal )
)
```

Comment: Fixed Thanks mate